# xunit.runner.dnx set configuration to use for running tests

Tags: xunit, dnx

I have noticed that when I use powershell to run my tests with the dnx runner it defaults to using the Debug configuration.  Is there any way to tell it to use a different configuration?

Something like

```
  "commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx -xml TestResults.xml -config Publish"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a DNX setting (and is passed on the DNX command line), not an xUnit.net command option.

```
dnx --configuration Release test
```